# Replace letters in string with numbers

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have this string `'=F*G'`

I want to replace it to numbers to be `'=6*7'`

I have successfully managed to replace letters with number using this code

```js
    var string = '=F*G'
        .toLowerCase().split('')
        .filter(c => c >= 'a' & c <= 'z')
        .map(c => c.charCodeAt(0) -  'a'.charCodeAt(0) + 1)
        .join(' ')

    console.log(string);
```

but this code removes the '=' and '*'
I need help keeping them in string after replacing letters with numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't filter the characters, or they won't be in the output to union back together. Try this.

```
    var string = '=F*G'
    .toLowerCase().split('')
    .map(c => {
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
            return c.charCodeAt(0) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0) + 1
        }
        return c;
    })
    .join('')

   console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a callback replacer function. This replacer function can use `String#charCodeAt()` to produce an ordinal value for each alphabetical character in the string.

```js
console.log("=F*G".replace(/[A-Z]/g, m => m.charCodeAt() - 64));
```

Use `[a-zA-Z]` or the `i` flag if you want to match both cases and generate different numbers per upper/lower letter. If you want to normalize both cases to produce the same digits, call `String#toUpperCase()` first before applying the provided code above (or use `toLowerCase()` as you're doing and change the ordinal subtraction value accordingly -- it doesn't matter).